# Dagger 2 unchecked warnings

Tags: java, android, lint, dagger-2, unchecked

In a project where I'm currently working on I've experienced some unchecked warnings related to **Dagger 2**.

To exclude project related factors I've tried compiling the **Dagger 2 examples** provided on GitHub and they are also causing these unchecked warnings. See below.

> /MY_DIRECTORY/../DaggerApplicationComponent.java:28: warning:
>   [unchecked] unchecked conversion
>
> this.demoApplicationMembersInjector = DemoApplication_MembersInjector.create((MembersInjector) MembersInjectors.noOp(), provideLocationManagerProvider);
>
> required: MembersInjector`<Application>`
>
> found:    MembersInjector

Apparently the create method requires an **MembersInjector`<Application>`** but **Dagger 2** casts the passed object to an **MembersInjector** by default.

I would like fix these issues so that the logs remain clean and the buildserver compiles the project again.

Some settings I'm using:

- Compile against Android version 23
- Dagger version 2.0.1
- Dagger compiler version 2.0.1
- Javax Annotation jsr250-api version 1.0

Comment: see https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/199

Comment: thanks! that fixed it!

Comment: What's the solution actually... is it getting the latest dagger2 or suppress the warning ourselves? (if suppress the warning ourselves, how could we do it?) Thanks.

Comment: Would be nice to post your solution here instead of a "thanks! that fixed it!"

Answer (score 1):

I tried to upgrade Dagger to latest version `2.19`, and the issue has gone.

See more: https://github.com/google/dagger/releases

Answer (score 0):

use

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

for your component class

that's work for me